# Deleting hidden value in the form on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I need to delete the hidden value that is created in the form

```
<div id="gotvalue">
</div>
```

Here my HTML Form will be empty and the div will get filled with the input value like this

```
<div id="gotvalue">
    <input type="hidden" id="imagetextbox" name="imagetextbox"/>
</div>
```

But once the form is submitted i want to delete element inside the `<div id="gotvalue">`

```
$("#gotvalue").remove();
```

also tried

```
$('#gotvalue').html('');
```

But the value is not being removed.

How can i remove that it ??

Note : I can't use `$("#imagetextbox").val('');` as it will empty only the value of the field .

Comment: which value you wanna remove?? there is only one hidden field inside it.....

Comment: I need to remove that entire hidden field i mean i should have only <div id="gotvalue">
</div

Comment: then `$('#gotvalue').html('');` will work perfectly , check your browser console for error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be `$('#gotvalue')`. Also, you say you want to empty the div, yet you are removing it from the DOM completely.

To achieve what you require you can either `empty()` the div, like this:

```
$('#gotvalue').empty();
```

Or you can remove the hidden input directly:

```
$('#imagetextbox').remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7zs4smo/)

---

If you want to leave the hidden field in place, but reset its value, you can use `val('')`:

```
$('#imagetextbox').val('');
```

Comment: Yes, i even tried that. But it didn't remove the content inside it

Comment: Have you checked for console errors? There's no reason this code alone wouldn't work.

Comment: @Rory : If i do so , its emptying for the first time and from next time onwards it won't even get the hidden field inside the gotvalue div right ?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Is this not the behaviour you want?

Comment: Yes, i mean it should able to get the hidden field on the next move, Is there any possiblity for it ?

Comment: In that case you don't want to empty the div. You just want to reset the hidden fields' value. See my update.

Comment: You mean to say .empty or .remove ??

Comment: No. If you need to keep the hidden input, use `val('')`. Your original question was about removing or emptying the div, yet your requirement is completely different. Please outline your questions clearly in fututre.

Comment: Yes i understand, but it will reset the value of hidden field right ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$('#gotvalue').html('');
```

Comment: Even, that didn't helped me

Comment: @Stackerman You should check your browser console for error. Or just pass an alert statement to check whether your function is working

Answer (score 1):

How about using `$('#gotvalue').html('');`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3c0x92q/)